# Cron script doesn't work unless called by sh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have a script saved in file named file.sh
It is executed by command

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

file.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
find /var/log/*.gz  -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n"|sort -n|tail -n +6|sudo xargs rm|echo"test"|wall
```

I am trying to execute it by cron job.

Crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
* * * * * root /etc/file.sh
```

Script is launched every minute by cron job, **I am getting echo in terminal.**

But **xargs rm doest works** . I do know why.

When I execute command sudo sh file.sh, is OK, and file is deleted.

Please help me find the reason why the script is not working in cron-job.
It's strange.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `printf` statement ... I'm fairly certain that you should also see error messages from `rm` in root's mail to the effect that e.g.:
`1634986839.0000000000 Sun 24 Oct 2021 12:00:39 AM UTC /var/log/syslog.2.gz` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes errors occurs, but, when i run this in sudo sh its works anyway.

Comment: And you realise that once the `*gz` files are gone it won't work a 2nd time?

Comment: Yes I do. it's script for delete the oldest logs files.

Comment: @GrafikKrystian your command is basically outputting all those metadata (since you are using -printf %T@ %Tc). filter those out before piping it to sudo xargs rm

Comment: @GrafikKrystian - how about you show us the output in mail from the cron-job run, then? Add it to your question ...

Comment: @GrafikKrystian Actually, the question I have is: how is it managing to run under `sudo sh`, since that `-printf` *will* be printing lots of metadata along with the filenames. BTW, the pipe from `xargs rm` to `echo` doesn't make any sense, since `rm` doesn't produce output and `echo` doesn't read input.

Comment: _does not work_ is not a very helpful error description. Unless you provide more details, I don't see how one can help you. Did you at least try run the script with `-x` turned on, to see what's going on?